# Shell: In-file converting first field of a text file from decimal to hexadecimal

Tags: bash, radix, inline-editing

This is my example text file:

```
$ cat RealVNC\ MRU.reg
"10"="Lamborghini-:1"
"16"="Terminus-"
"20"="Midnighter-:5915"
"35"="ThreepWood-:1"
"81"="Midnighter-:1"
"58"="Midnighter-"
```

And I would like to **convert** values of the **first field** (the numbers between `""`) from **decimal to hexadecimal** (it is a .reg file for Windows, so I meesed it up thinking the numbers were in a decimal base, and now the file is too long to manually edit).

Example result that I need to obtain:

```
$ cat Hex\ RealVNC\ MRU.reg
"0A"="Lamborghini-:1"
"10"="Terminus-"
"14"="Midnighter-:5915"
"23"="ThreepWood-:1"
"51"="Midnighter-:1"
"3A"="Midnighter-"
```

As can be seen, **only the numbers** have changed.
Resulting numbers must be two characters long (RegEdit considers them different).
Changes in the **order of the lines** don't bother here, but I think it would be more "clean" a solution that doesn't change it.

I don't expect any number (be it decimal or hex) will have more than **2 characters**, but a solution that considers this possibility will be best (as it is a more generic solution).

I have tested so far:

```
$ cat RealVNC\ MRU.reg | awk -F \" '{print $2}'
10
16
20
35
81
58
```

But I don't know who to in-line make the changes from dec to hex.

My shell is usually Bash, but other shell-derivated solutions (like Perl or Python) are accepted too.

Comment: Did you solve it ? if yes please mark  the most useful answer as accepted.

Comment: As long as it is not again rules, I use to allow more time for: a) More tests on the answers. b) More possible answers. c) More suggestions/corrections/details. I prefer to accept answers a few weeks later than too soon that I will need to correct my choice.

Answer (score 3):

A simple `awk`:

```
awk -F\" '$2=sprintf("%02X", $2)' OFS=\" file
"0A"="Lamborghini-:1"
"10"="Terminus-"
"14"="Midnighter-:5915"
"23"="ThreepWood-:1"
"51"="Midnighter-:1"
"3A"="Midnighter-"
```

**Explanation**

- `-F\"` : sets field separator (`FS`) to `"`
- `$2=sprintf("%02X", $2)` : `$2` is assigned to it’s printed
  version ( `sprintf`)  with a `%02X` mask in hexadecimal using the
  letters 'A' to 'F' for hex digits greater than 9 and a two digits
  width with `0` padding
- `OFS=\"` : sets the **O**utput **FS**  to match **FS**

The `$2` assignation  is always *true* and no additional action is given , `awk` always displays the results as it's default action.

Comment: Nice and simple solution, +1 Didn't know about `OFS`

Comment: To clarify OP is setting the variable OFS outside the main awk script: It could be written as: `awk 'BEGIN{FS="\"";OFS="\""};$2=sprintf("%02X", $2)'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use perl - when using the [substitution operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html) with the `e` flag you can pass a function to handle the replace value:

```
echo abc | perl -ne 's/(.+)/uc($1);print/e' # ABC
```

You can then use [`sprintf` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) to convert decimal to hex with the `%X` conversion:

> `%x    an unsigned integer, in hexadecimal`
>   `%X    like %x, but using upper-case letters`

```
$ cat RealVNC\ MRU.reg | perl -ne 's/^"(.*?)"/sprintf("\"%X\"", $1)/e;print;'
"A"="Lamborghini-:1"
"10"="Terminus-"
"14"="Midnighter-:5915"
"23"="ThreepWood-:1"
"51"="Midnighter-:1"
"3A"="Midnighter-"
```

If you want leading zero on 0-F single values you can use the prefix format `%02X`:

```
%02X
 ^^L Conversion
 |L Result length
 L- Prefix char
```

And the result:

```
$ cat RealVNC\ MRU.reg | perl -ne 's/^"(.*?)"/sprintf("\"%02X\"", $1)/e;print;'
"0A"="Lamborghini-:1"
"10"="Terminus-"
"14"="Midnighter-:5915"
"23"="ThreepWood-:1"
"51"="Midnighter-:1"
"3A"="Midnighter-"
```

Comment: Seems to be working, but I made a typo on the question (corrected now): `A` must be `0A` (all numbers must be 2 characters long). Anyway, your method seems to fail only with `{10..15}`, and I can edit these 6 numbers by hand. Thanks you.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Yes i actually though that when I read as well.. simple use the printf prefix style `%02X` (see edit)