# Shell: converting any number in a text file from decimal to hexadecimal

Tags: shell, radix, inline-editing

In a slightly different question from [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336086/bash-in-file-converting-first-field-of-a-text-file-from-decimal-to-hexadecimal), I would like to convert any number in a text file from **decimal to hexadecimal**.

A number is here defined by `a set of numeric characters together`.

Example:

```
$ cat MyFile.txt
Hello,10,Good255Bye-boys01
```

Must become:

```
Hello,0A,GoodFFBye-boys01
```

Valid too:

```
Hello,A,GoodFFBye-boys1
```

Methods that allow (first case) to specify the character wide (to obtain `0A` instead of `A`) are preferred.

I have tested `grep` to extract the numbers piped to `bc` to convert them:

```
( echo "obase=16" ; cat Line.txt  |grep -o '[0-9]*') | bc
```

but this method shows only one (converted to hex) number each line, and removes the rest of the characters.

Comment: Bash isn't the right choice. You need something with better regex capabilities. For instance, this is trivial in Python, with `re.sub`.

Comment: Actually, looking at that previous question I wonder why you did not accept any of the answers, as they appear to do exactly what you asked. So far you have only accepted answers to 6 out of your 37 questions.

Comment: @Jongware: the answers on the other question are only are only a few minutes old. I use to give some weeks for people to propose new questions. Some people think that marking as accepted helps the community, but I prefer to wait to be sure. As you could see, I bother the community, for example answering my own questions when I found the solution; example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563471/windows-shell-how-can-i-get-the-audio-devices-names . Another handicap: I really dislike to remove the "accepted" mark of any question.

Comment: Since you paid no attention to my comment, I actually wrote the code for you. Pick the right tool for the right job.

Comment: Attemp posted, @AvinashRaj . It is not much. I was thinking that the link to the origin question coud be considered as an attempt. Probably 4ae1e1 is right and Bash is not the best tool for this, so I was really lost and without ideas.

Comment: @4ae1e1 : I don't think "someone writing the code for the original poster" fits to the soul of StackExchange sites. I have shown my attemps and the origin of the question, you wrote a solution, and the result is a wiki-like document useful for those arriving here in search for the same.

Comment: The problem is that your attempt is simply way too far from your goal, and you won't reach anywhere if you chase that path.

Comment: @4ae1e1 : Python and Perl use to be considered as valid answers for any Linux shell related question, or so I have seen until now. I don't know why. Maybe due to its integration with the operating system. It could be worth to define such details in the rules. Meanwhile, accepting Python and Perl seems a constructive way to  build a forum to me.

Comment: SO is about pointing people to the right direction, not granting every wish to go from point A to B, when point B is further away from the destination.

Comment: Also, grep and bc are external commands. They are no more native to the shell than Python or Perl. You can of course solve this problem in pure bash, but as I said, you should use the right tool for the right job.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're okay with using `grep` and `bc` in a pipe, it's clear that you don't want a solution in pure `sh`, but are happy to use external tools.

```
perl -pe 's/([0-9]+)/sprintf "%02X", $1/ge' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Indeed, a Perl solution is perfectly valid since it is a common tool for Linux's shells. The yours seems to work fine. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

A Python solution (thanks to the suggestion from user *4ae1e1*):

```
$ cat convert.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import fileinput
import re

for line in fileinput.input():
    print(re.sub("\d+", lambda matchobj: "%X" % int(matchobj.group(0)), line), end="")
```

Example usage:

```
cat MyFile.txt | ./convert.py
```

or:

```
./convert.py MyFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

dec2hex command will do the task.